# Convert from char to operator Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, char, type-conversion, operators

Is there any way to convert a char, lets say with a value of '+', into the operator +? Something like this:

```
println(1 charOperator 1);
```

output:

```
2
```

Comment: For which operators will you need this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
fun operatorFromChar(charOperator: Char):(Int, Int)->Int
{
    return when(charOperator)
    {
        '+'->{a,b->a+b}
        '-'->{a,b->a-b}
        '/'->{a,b->a/b}
        '*'->{a,b->a*b}
        else -> throw Exception("That's not a supported operator")
    }
}
```

and later call:

```
println(operatorFromChar('+').invoke(1,1))
```

Operators are, at the end of the way, functions. If you return a function with the operator's job, you can invoke it as it was the operator itself, but it will never be as "pretty" as calling the operator directly.

Comment: You can invoke it like this as well: operatorFromChar('+')(1,1) :) +1

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
infix fun Int.`_`(that: Int) = this + that
```

where the backtick is unnecessary to this character but maybe necessary for other character. Then you can try:

```
println(2 _ 3) // output: 5
```

**Update** according to the comment:

I mean something like

```
val expr = input.split(' ')
when (expr[1])
{
    '+' -> return expr[0].toInt() + expr[2].toInt()
    '-' -> return expr[0].toInt() - expr[2].toInt()
    '*' -> return expr[0].toInt() * expr[2].toInt()
    '/' -> return expr[0].toInt() / expr[2].toInt()
    // add more branches
}
```

However, I was wondering whether there is a better and tricky solution from the grammar of Kotlin.

Comment: I was looking for a dynamic way, so for example '-' becomes - and '+' becomes +

Comment: I'm not so clear of the saying "with a value of '+'". Do you mean you are writing a calculator accepting a string input or a `eval` function?

Comment: im making a calculator, and want the user to be able to choose operator

Comment: The very first solution I can think to your question is to `when` match the second character and do the corresponding thing to the converted first and third string, something like `when (expression[1]) { '+' -> return expression[0].toInt() + expression[1].toInt() }`. Maybe there is a better and tricky solution which I am waiting for, too.

Comment: Or something like "converting infix to postfix", etc. You may asking an X - Y question.

Comment: Im not sure if i understand what youre saying here Geno

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really possible. Maybe you should add your current solution and there's another way to help you out.

Here's a sneaky solution for calculating expressions with `+` and `-` only:

```
val exp = "10+44-12+3"

val result = exp.replace("-", "+-").split("+").sumBy { it.toInt() }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you basically want is an `Char` to **result** of an operation mapping. So, I decided to return the result right away and not a lambda.

```
fun Int.doOperation(charOperator: Char, x: Int) = when(charOperator) {
    '+' -> this + x
    '-' -> this - x
    '/' -> this / x
    '*' -> this * x
    else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Not supported")
}
```

Using an extension function maybe (?) makes the syntax a little nicer. You decide.

Call site:

```
println(5.doOperation('+', 6))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the interpreter class in [beanshell](https://beanshell.github.io/) library
to convert string text automatically to result
for example

```
interpreter.eval("equal=2*3")
println(interpreter.get("equal").toString().toDouble().toString())
```

or can use expression class that does the same thing

Answer (score 0):

```
fun String.stringToConditionalOperators(): (Boolean, Boolean) -> Boolean {
    return when (this.lowercase(Locale.getDefault())) {
        "and" -> {
            { a: Boolean, b: Boolean ->
                a && b
            }
        }
        "or" -> {
            { a: Boolean, b: Boolean ->
                a || b
            }
        }
        // You can add more operator 
        else -> {
            return { a: Boolean, b: Boolean ->
                a || b
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage..

```
val operator = "AND"
operator.stringToConditionalOperators().invoke(one, two)
```